# Restored database missing views, stored procs and foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, ssms

I'm trying to create a copy of a database in SQL Management Studio (SQL Server Express) using Backup-Restore.  Local to local.  When I do it it copies tables and data, but ignores views, stored procedures and foreign keys.

Object Explorer -> write-click "Databases" -> "Restore Database..." -> put in a name -> select a "from" database -> go

This is the script that gets generated:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [DbName_raw] 
FROM  DISK = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\Backup\DbName.bak.1' 
WITH  FILE = 1,
MOVE N'GeoDo' TO N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DbName_raw.mdf',  
MOVE N'GeoDo_log' TO N'c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA\DbName_raw_1.ldf',  
NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
```

Database appears in Object Explorer but with views, stored procs ad foreign keys missing.  Can't see anything obvious in the settings of the wizard.  What am I missing?

Comment: As far as I can tell, this was because of an old backup file. Restoring from a database restores from backups taken from that database, rather than the database itself.  Waiting until the 8 hours are up and I can post this myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was because of an old backup file. I was under the impression that backing up from a database would just copy what was there currently, but it turns out that the backups come from snapshots taken of the database instead.  Those backups did not contain the missing views, stored procedures and foreign keys.

Answer (score 4):

Backup and restore will transfer anything in that database, even views and procedures. You *must* be doing wrong something else. Are you looking at the wrong database? Or is the restore failing?

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Yeah I thought it was odd.  Found what the issue is.  Waiting for the 8 hours until I can post this:  "As far as I can tell, this was because of an old backup file.  Restoring from a database restores from backups taken from that database, rather than the database itself."

Comment: Also, the restore was not failing, and I was looking at the correct database.